# Why can't I use EXIT_SUCCESS instead of 0 in the return statement in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, return, program-entry-point, exit

Why can't I use EXIT_SUCCESS instead of 0 in the return statement in Visual Studio Code? I get the error:

> id "EXIT_SUCCESS" is not defined

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Thanks for help");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; /*problem*/
}
```

Comment: Because EXIT_SUCCESS is not defined.

Comment: I recommend routinely looking up the reference information the bits of the standard libraries that you use, especially for anything in the vicinity of an error message or unexpected behavior.  A web search for `c EXIT_SUCCESS` returns links to quality reference pages that tell you where its defined (`<stdlib.h>`), what it's intended for (primarily with `exit` function, but also with return from `main`), and caveats on how to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definitions of the `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` macros are in the "stdlib.h" header file, so you need to `#include <stdlib.h>` in order to use them.

(Some compilers may implicitly include that header when you include "stdio.h" but you can't rely on that behaviour.)

Answer (score 1):

Because `EXIT_SUCCESS` is located in `stdlib.h` and you didn't include it.